# Why can I append to a file but not overwrite it?

Tags: io-redirection

If I do this:

```
iptables -nvL > output.txt
```

`output.txt` ends up empty. If I do:

```
iptables -nvL >> output.txt
```

It works fine. Appending is working, but overwriting is not. Why?

Comment: Are you running both as root and/or with sudo? What are the permissions on the directory and file?

Comment: I am running with root.

Comment: Did you actually typo the name (`ouput.txt`), or is that just in the question?

Comment: Yes I typed the correct name.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have the `noclobber` option enabled in your shell. This protects existing files from being overwritten by output redirection. To disable it, run `set +o noclobber`. Probably `noclobber` is set somewhere in your `.bashrc`, `/etc/profile` or other equivalent file.

See also `man set` or `man bash` for details.

Comment: That would result in the file getting zeroed out? That seems like a poor protection

Comment: No, empty file is not the result of `noclobber` but of the fact that it has been created earlier and nothing was written to it.